# Choosing hexadecimal web colours

Tags: macos, color, image-editing

How can I choose hexadecimal web colours (like #000000 and #fffff) to use in system and third party apps? *(e.g. an image editor like GraphicConverter)*

Comment: Things I've tried which haven't worked: I've checked the manual and Google of course, and I've tried looking through the default Apple color picker which I could swear used to let you choose this (I'm now on OS X 10.7).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Skala Color](http://bjango.com/mac/skalacolor/) is another solution, that works very well in the latest versions of Mac OSX.

[image]

You can select HEX to appear in place of the RGB code, which appears in the above picture.

I used Hex Color Picker for a long time but finally got tired of it trying to be smarter than me. Frequently I would type a single character and it filled in all 6 values for that same number; other times I would get through 2 characters and Hex Color Picker would repeat that. For whatever reason, I had to constantly copy/paste values into the picker, because it kept thinking it knew what I wanted (it didn't).

Comment: I just installed this. It only works now with TextEdit and Mail. No longer works with Pages, Keynote or Numbers. You will need to use the answer from @user173032.

Answer (score 5):

In newer versions of the stock OS X Colors utility: Select sliders from the toolbar and then "RGB Sliders" in the drop down - this will allow you to both read and enter RGB values hex:

[image]

Not sure in which version of OS X this was introduced, but it's relatively newish.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Hex Color Picker](http://wafflesoftware.net/hexpicker/):

[image]

Comment: this tool is abandoned now

Comment: I'm finding it not as stable with newer versions of OS.

Comment: I did some more checking. It only works now with TextEdit and Mail. No longer works with Pages, Keynote or Numbers. You will need to use the answer from @user173032.