# How to extend the standard color picker to pick and edit HEX colors?

Tags: macos, color

In Ask Different there are similar threads (e.g. [Choosing hexadecimal web colours](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/78896/choosing-hexadecimal-web-colours)), but unfortunately no one is resolutive for me.

The perfect solution would be [Hex Color Picker](http://wafflesoftware.net/hexpicker/) (a plugin for the standard picker), because it goes beyond picking allowing to edit/create swatches also. Unfortunately, it does not work for me: for some reason the hex picker returns wrong hex values. E.g. a full red image (#ff0000) created in photoshop, is evaluated as #f70016 (see image below). I tested this behaviour picking both from Photoshop and from an exported .png opened in browser. Both in Maverick and Mountain Lion.

Can you suggest me an alternative solution or a fix for this issue?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could add the other threads as easy reference.

Comment: Can you try it in other applications besides Photoshop?

Comment: I've tried to export the ff0000 png and then picking it from Firefox: picked value is always #f70016

Answer (score 3):

Test it and you'll see that Photoshop is guilty for not rendering in the same color space.

You need to change the color profile of your image in photoshop.

Answer (score 3):

Just use **DigitalColor Meter that ships with Osx:** to turn on hex visualization go to
View > Show values > Hexadecimal (I've got it in italian so it can translated slightly different)

[image: DigitalColor Meter]
[image: Set hex visualization]

Comment: That is not what he is asking. The values he gets from the tool is different from what he entered in Photoshop.

Comment: For me works flawlessly, digitalcolor meter show the same values of photoshop

Comment: Chance the color space of your image :)

Answer (score 2):

Jesper, the creator of Hex Color Picker here.

In most cases, clicking Options in the Hex Color Picker part of the color picker and toggling the check box mentioning calibrated colors will do the trick. The triangle at the top right means that the color is a device color, i.e. that it has been changed, and that the color code is the color after the correction.

I have come to the conclusion that it may be impossible to always pick the right color code for a number of reasons, or at least that it is well beyond my understanding. I have gone several back-and-forths with different people at various points in time, and no solution worked for all scenarios. I think in those cases, it may come down to either or both of color calibration on the display color profile and special color space adjustments in the particular application - the magnifying glass (which by the way is part of the OS X color panel and provided by it since it shows up in all the other pickers too) just doesn't know what it's picking at that point.

That said, there are simpler cases than that that still mess up. I am still a novice in color management (although not for a lack of trying) and I would be delighted to be proven wrong. The source code to Hex Color Picker is available for anyone to fiddle with, and it is effectively abandonware by now. I still use it myself but I mostly don't have the opportunity to get anything done on it.

I also use [Developer Color Picker](http://download.panic.com/picker/), which may or may not have these problems.

Answer (score 0):

Oh sorry.. In Yosemite finally we got an integrated hex color picker, but if you've got Mavericks and older, try [hexpicker](http://wafflesoftware.net/hexpicker/), I tried it and it works flawlessly.